# Understanding the Light propagation through multimode fibers

Tags: electromagnetism, fiber-optics

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me clarify the theory behind this.
I am playing with this code found on Github, https://github.com/wavefrontshaping/pyMMF to simulate the light propagation in step-index multimode fibers. According to this formula found in this paper, https://www.nature.com/articles/nphoton.2015.112 [image: formula], where T is the conversion matrix, M is the transmission matrix, the converted transmission matrix, and Mo_bar should be a diagonal matrix (for the ideal case and straight fibers), however, I am getting a non-diagonal matrix, which I don't understand. I know it means mode coupling is present but for a simulation for an ideal case, that should give me a diagonal matrix, right? What is that I am missing in the concept here?[image: output]

```
Edit: code here
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[145]:


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyMMF
import pandas as pd


# In[146]:


NA = 0.095
radius = 40 # in microns
areaSize = 2.4*radius # calculate the field on an area larger than the diameter of the fiber
npoints_modes = 50 # resolution of the window
n1 = 1.5 # index of refraction at r=0 (maximum)
wl = 1.064 # wavelength in microns
curvature = None
k0 = 2.*np.pi/wl


# In[147]:


# Create the fiber object
profile = pyMMF.IndexProfile(npoints = npoints_modes, areaSize = areaSize)

# Initialize the index profile
profile.initStepIndex(n1=n1,a=radius,NA=NA)

# Instantiate the solver
solver = pyMMF.propagationModeSolver()

# Set the profile to the solver
solver.setIndexProfile(profile)

# Set the wavelength
solver.setWL(wl)

# Estimate the number of modes for a graded index fiber
Nmodes_estim = pyMMF.estimateNumModesSI(wl,radius,NA,pola=2)

print(f"Estimated number of modes using the V number = {Nmodes_estim}")


# In[148]:


def get_modes(npoints):
    profile = pyMMF.IndexProfile(npoints = npoints, areaSize = areaSize)
    profile.initStepIndex(n1=n1,a=radius,NA=NA)

    solver = pyMMF.propagationModeSolver()
    solver.setIndexProfile(profile)
    solver.setWL(wl)
#     modes = solver.solve(mode='SI',
#                         curvature = None,
#                         r_max = r_max, # max radius to calculate (and first try for large radial boundary condition)
#                         dh = dh, # radial resolution during the computation
#                         min_radius_bc = 1.5, # min large radial boundary condition
#                         change_bc_radius_step = 0.95, #change of the large radial boundary condition if fails 
#                         N_beta_coarse = 1000, # number of steps of the initial coarse scan
#                         degenerate_mode = 'exp',
#                         )
    modes = solver.solve(mode = 'SI', degenerate_mode = 'exp', curvature = None)
    return modes

modes = get_modes(npoints_modes)


# In[149]:


i_modes = np.arange(0,3,1)

M0 = modes.getModeMatrix()
ma = []
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'qt')
for i in i_modes:
    Mi = M0[...,i]
    profile = Mi.reshape([npoints_modes]*2)
    ma.append(profile.flatten())
    plt.figure(figsize = (4,4))
    plt.imshow(colorize(profile,'jet'))
    
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title(f'Mode {i} (l={modes.l[i]}, m={modes.m[i]})')
    # save figure


# In[116]:


M0_ = np.conj(M0).T  #unitary matrix
p = modes.getPropagationMatrix(10)


# In[142]:


M0_final = np.matmul(M0,np.matmul(p,M0_))  #M_var = T*M*T*


# In[143]:


M0_finaldf = pd.DataFrame(data = M0_final, index = None, columns = None)


# In[144]:


M0_finaldf


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: Interesting paper. Without looking at the code, perhaps some suggestions. I suspect some numerical errors accumulating or potentially a set up error, it seems from the paper that everything is pretty sensitive and they had to play with a lot of variables to make it work out. A) try small number of modes first. 4 or 5 instead of lots. B) try for shorter lengths, very short first then lengthen and see what happens to the matrices. C) restrict yourself to a subset of polarizations choosing nice ones first. Does it have an example you can run that ‘works’?

Comment: I have added the code in the updated post above.

Comment: Sorry not to be more help. That’s pretty high level code looks like a good way to implement. The details would be in the solvers and their accuracy, but maybe trying some shorter fibers or smaller number of modes can help figure out where the problems might be.

Comment: I had the same problem for the code i wrote. The problem is not in the code but in my understanding, but i think i will try to do for smaller modes. Thanks :)